How to prevent variables from resetting after I press a JButton within Action Event method?
I am currently working on a number calculator using Java GUI but when I create the variables within the Action Event method, their values resets each time I press a button. I could not figure out how to create them elsewhere either.
Here is the code so far:
(I only included the part where it has this issue)
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String values = "";
    String sign = "";
    int number1 = 0;
    int number2 = 0;

    if (event.getSource()== oneButton) {
        displayTextField.setText(displayTextField.getText() + "1");
        values = values + "1";
        System.out.println(values);
    } else if (event.getSource()== twoButton) {
        displayTextField.setText(displayTextField.getText() + "2");
        values = values + "2";
    } else if (event.getSource()== threeButton) {
        displayTextField.setText(displayTextField.getText() + "3");
        values = values + "3";
    } else if (event.getSource()== fourButton) {
        displayTextField.setText(displayTextField.getText() + "4");
        values = values + "4";
    } else if (event.getSource()== fiveButton) {
        displayTextField.setText(displayTextField.getText() + "5");
        values = values + "5";
    } else if (event.getSource()== sixButton) {
        displayTextField.setText(displayTextField.getText() + "6");
        values = values + "6";
    } else if (event.getSource()== sevenButton) {
        displayTextField.setText(displayTextField.getText() + "7");
        values = values + "7";
    } else if (event.getSource()== eightButton) {
        displayTextField.setText(displayTextField.getText() + "8");
        values = values + "8";
    } else if (event.getSource()== nineButton) {
        displayTextField.setText(displayTextField.getText() + "9");
        values = values + "9";
    } else if (event.getSource()== zeroButton) {
        displayTextField.setText(displayTextField.getText() + "0");
        values = values + "0";
    } else if (event.getSource()== plusButton) {
        displayTextField.setText("");
        //(this is where the problem occurs since it's trying to cast an empty string, which caused the resetting issue of "value")
        number1 = Integer.valueOf(values);
        values = "";
        sign = "+";
    }
}

I tried to declare the variables elsewhere but their scope wouldn't cover the Action Event method. I also wouldn't be able to make them global either since they are not constants. Therefore, I could not prevent "value" from resetting each time an event occurs from pressing a button.

Simple: don't declare and initialize the variables that need to persist within the method but rather within the class.

"I tried to declare the variables elsewhere but their scope wouldn't cover the Action Event method" -- then you're doing something wrong. Show that attempt please.

"(I only included the part where it has this issue)" -- you should include a [mre].

I forgot to consider that! Appreciate your reminder. It has been fixed

I would do something like my answer here and avoid all those if-else blocks.
